# Slick2D - Animation scaling and movement for an intro?

Tags: java, slick2d

http://puu.sh/gdopH/3a39a2e0ab.gif

This is my current state of where I'm at with the animation.
However, instead of going up straight with the scaling and movement, it first bounces to the left and then goes in a curve up to where it should be.

This is my current code:

```
  private float scale = 1f;
  private int introX = 1024, introY = 360;
  private boolean introSpinning = false;

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer gameContainer, Graphics graphics) throws SlickException {
        if(mode == Mode.MENU) {
            Animation anim = Player.iFacing[Direction.LEFT.ordinal()]; // Fetching the player animation.
            if(introSpinning) {
                anim = Player.spinAnim;
                if(scale <= 3f)
                    scale += 0.01f;
                if(introY > 100)
                    introY -= 2;
                graphics.scale(scale, scale);
                graphics.drawAnimation(anim, introX - ((scale / 3) * 350), introY - (scale * 20));
            }
            else {
                if(introX > 508)
                    introX -= 2;
                else {
                    introSpinning = true;
                }
                graphics.drawAnimation(anim, introX, introY);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it on my own :)
Had to change the `drawAnimation` to different math:

```
graphics.drawAnimation(anim, introX / scale - (anim.getWidth() / 3), introY / scale);
```

**~ Lordmau5.**